# Is there anyway to retrieve a user's watch history after the api depreciation in September?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

My users sign in using their google accounts. 
Is there a way to retrieve their youtube watch history currently?
I am aware that that was possible before last September, but then they canceled the method. Is there any alternative out there?

Answer (score 0):

This is the same issue as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38908308/how-to-get-watch-later-playlist-details-after-september-12th), since the `Watch later` and `History` playlists behave in the same way.

Retrieval of items for those two playlists has been disabled as of September 2016. Unfortunately, as of yet there is no documented alternative way.